Clearing Specific Range of the Row Of the Cell that Matches another Cell from other spread sheet
I am new to Excel VBA and I would need your help for the VBA code
I have two spreadsheets One Named "January" and "Registry"
If value in Cell "D3" Of Registry Matches Any Cell in "January" Spreadsheet, It will clear Contents of Cell E6:AJ6 in "January" Spreadsheet
Much Appreciated for your help.

SO is not a free code writing service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into issues. When that happens, you can explain the problem you're having, include the relevant portions of your code, and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to help. Start with doing some searching here - there are lots of existing questions that should give you a place to start.

You have posted too little information. To not leave empty-handed, create a sub in a new standard module (e.g. Module1) of a new workbook and experiment with (tweak) the following: With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("January"): If Not .UsedRange.Find(.Parent.Sheets("Registry").Range("D3").Value, , , xlWhole) Is Nothing Then .Range("E6:AJ6").ClearContents: End With every colon denoting a new line. Make sure you have both worksheets renamed appropriately. If you don't get it to work as required, come back and post the code you ended up with describing why it doesn't work for you.

This screenshot illustrates how the code in my previous comment works. Here is a more reasonable scenario: for each cell in January!A6:A_LastRow, if the value in January!A? matches the value in cell Registry!D3, clear the contents in January!E?:AJ?. Note I introduced a new element: column A in sheet January. Use the information in my comments to edit your post adding an accurate description of the requirement. Also, add your code, some sample data as text, and screenshots of the before and the after.

This is one workaround:
If Not Worksheets("January").Cells.Find(Worksheets("Registry").Range("D3")) Is Nothing Then
  Worksheets("January").Range("E6:AJ6").Clear
End If

